# Start-job not working with findstr

Tags: powershell, start-job

I am a begineer in Powershell, and I am unable to make this piece of code working

the findstr never output the expected file on disk

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    param (
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    [string]$one,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    [string]$two,
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    [string]$three)
    $run = findstr /i """$two""" $one > $three\$($one)$($two).csv
} -Name "Import_$($FilterUSNString)_$($fileName)" -ArgumentList "$global:folder\$fileName", $FilterUSNString, $Global:defaultoutputlocation
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please provide an example of what you want the output to look like.

Comment: Why are you using `findstr` in a PowerShell job and not `Select-String`?

Comment: Why are you assigning to $run if you're trying to output the result to a file?  Remove the assignment, and then you should get something in the file.  I think you're getting the equivalent of `($run = ...) > file.txt`.  The assignment has no output, so nothing ends up in the file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am dealing with 2gb csv files and findstr is way faster. select string remains a valid options, I was just trying to gain 50% of the time on the same operation.

Comment: PS C:\temp> Measure-Command -Expression {Select-String -Path .\largefile_.csv -Pattern "cmd"}

Measure-Command -Expression {findstr /I "CMD" .\largefile_.csv}


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 10
---------------------------------
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 4